# Display Telephone field on create account page in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0

I want to display telephone field on create account page along with the first name and last name. Telephone field is mapped to Address Fields so cannot display telephone field separately and hiding the other address fields. 
Help me to display just the telephone field and not the address fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace the following html file by above given code :- "vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping-address\address-renderer\default.html**

```html
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="shipping-address-item" data-bind="css: isSelected() ? 'selected-item' : 'not-selected-item'">
    <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --><br/>
     <!-- ko text: address().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko if: (address().isEditable()) -->
    <button type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            data-bind="click: editAddress, visible: address().isEditable()">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```